# Share NSArray instance to KVO objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a controller class that store a list of contact and I need to share this list to objects that will implement KVO on such array.

The most obvious solution is to use a NSArray instead of NSMutableArray, in order that everyone can use the same instance variable of the controller and it's not possible modify the content of the array.

Now, let's image that this list can change every 3 minutes and only the controller can update the content of the array.

If I dealloc and re-init the contact list array, all my KVO objects will lost the reference to my array.

Finally: 
NSArray PRO: No one can alter the content of the array
NSArray CON: The controller can not modify the array without a dealloc, so other objects lost the reference.

NSMutableArray PRO: Controller can modify array content, all the object can easily share the same reference of the array
NSMutableArray CON: Everyone can modify the array.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

`NSArray` in my opinion, given that it isn't being updated very often.

The object that owns and modifies the array exposes it through a property of type `NSArray*`.  The observers observe this property.  Whenever the object that owns the array recreates it, it sets the property to the new NSArray which then triggers KVO on all of the observers.

Alternatively, you can implement the [indexed accessor patterns](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB) for the property.